# Are "they gave him a round of applause" and "they gave him a round of claps" the same?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

ChatGPT says

> While "round of applause" is a common phrase in English, "round of
> claps" is not typically used in the same context. "Applause" refers to
> the sound of people clapping their hands together as an expression of
> approval or appreciation, whereas "claps" on its own does not
> necessarily have the same connotation of approval or appreciation.
>
> That being said, it's possible to use "claps" in other contexts where
> the action of clapping is emphasized, such as in describing a rhythmic
> pattern of clapping or the sound of hands clapping together. In those
> cases, "round of claps" might make more sense. However, in the context
> of expressing approval or appreciation, "round of applause" is the
> more commonly used phrase.

I agree with ChatGPT. It seems like "**a round of claps**" has its scope bigger than "**a round of applause**".

So, in which situation do we say "**they gave them a round of claps**"?

Comment: There are ***no***  situations in which we say "they gave him a round of claps", because [it's not idiomatically valid.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+round+of+applause%2Ca+round+of+claps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) You can get chatgpt to say stupid things if you press it.

Comment: And a "clap" is generally [not something you want to get](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/blog/what-is-the-clap) (*“The clap” is a slang term for gonorrhea.*)

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/collocations/british/clap and https://www.wordreference.com/englishcollocations/clap and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/hand-clapping and finally, https://ozdic.com/collocation/clap

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you don't have to press ChatGPT very hard to get it to say stupid things.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It's going great guns for me! I never really put the effort in with Linux command scripts, but even though not every script chatgpt writes is flawless, it's nearly always a doddle to see what's wrong and fix it. And it's saved me countless hours doing anything *slightly* out of the ordinary with the near-impenetrable QT Creator development system. But I was a bit fazed last night listening to people who understand LLM capabilities better than me discussing how even an unsophisticated bad actor could soon use it to develop the next Covid (that only infects "undesirable" people).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have lived and breathed Bash for over 20 years, and more recently Perl and Ruby. I hate Python with a passion. I would much prefer to make my own mistakes and fix them, than let a bot have all the fun.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I've never had much luck getting useful tech support from any SO sites for my own questions (though I often end up solving my problem by finding *someone else's* question on the same issue). If I post my *current* scripting problem on Super User, would you be willing to at least look at it? Essentially, it's a 3-line bash script run via ssh on a Raspberry Pi kicking off a "restartable" rsync job to copy a big file from my Pi to a friend's Linux Mint PC. And *sometimes* when I Ctrl/Z ... bg ... detach .. exit from the Pi, the copy continues. Other times it just stalls the copy!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I know a bit of Javascript and I asked Chatgpt to fix my wrong code, but it couldn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - go for it. Are you using the same screen name? I forgot to mention my love of Pis. Don't forget to mention the OS version.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: [Reliably detach from a Raspberry Pi rsync process and leave it running](https://superuser.com/questions/1789215/reliably-detach-from-a-raspberry-pi-rsync-process-and-leave-it-running). Ran "full-upgrade" on Pi recently, PC running latest Mint 21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A round of claps* is not an idiomatic English expression.

You could say *they give him a clap*, but that sounds less enthusiastic than *they give him a round of applause*.

(Having said that, *they give him a round of applause* might also mean a perfunctory applause with little enthusiasm).

The iWeb corpus has 2112 instances of "a round of applause", and one single instance of "a round of claps", and that single use is referring to using claps on the soundtrack of a song, not to applause.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind for me with *a round of claps* was a circle of elderly Spanish women taking it in turn to provide the claps to accompany flamenco dancers. Not that those "clappers" normally have to be very quick, but if they were *very* old perhaps they simply couldn't keep up without taking turns!

Answer (score 1):

We can use Google Ngram viewer to see how often words or phrases are used.

"Round of claps" is very rare, but is becoming slightly more common. Still, it is only about 1 in 2,500,000,000. ["Round of applause" is about 79,000 times more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=round%20of%20applause%2Fround%20of%20claps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)